# Using @MainActor to replace await keyword

Tags: swift, combine

I have a function that runs in the main view model to listen for Auth Status changes and perform actions.

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel {

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        // Listen for auth status changes
        Task(priority: .high) {
            await listenForAuthStatusChanges()
        }
    }
    
    
    // When auth status changes to true setup service
    @MainActor
    private func listenForAuthStatusChanges() async {
        SessionManager.shared.$isAuthenticated
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { isAuthenticated in
                if isAuthenticated == true {
                    self.setupService()
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
    .../
```

`SessionManager.isAuthenticated` is a Published property

```
@Published private(set) var isAuthenticated: Bool? = nil
```

If I remove `@MainActor` then I get an error `Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'` and I have to add `await` before `SessionManager.shared.$isAuthenticated` to satisfy the error.

1. `SessionManager.shared.$isAuthenticated` is not an async function, it's a simple published property. Why would you have to `await` a published property?
2. What does `@MainActor` have to do with async/await and why does it's use negate the need for the `await`?

```
    private func listenForAuthStatusChanges() async {
        await SessionManager.shared.$isAuthenticated
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { isAuthenticated in
                if isAuthenticated == true {
                    self.setupService()
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
```

Comment: Why is session manager on the MainActor? Mixing GCD and actors is usually a source of issues. Have you turned on “strict concurrency”? Does this pass swift  6 muster?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. SessionManager is a `@MainActor` which inherently makes the calling of all its methods and properties async, when called from a background context. By marking `@MainActor` on the caller, then both caller and callee are on the main thread.

Comment: Close, but do not say "thread". Swift structured concurrency is about _actors_. It's okay to say "context", though; in fact, that's a very useful term when understanding structured concurrency. "SessionManager is a @MainActor which inherently makes the calling of all its methods and properties async" You're saying that very badly — its methods and properties do not magically become async — but I think you mean the right thing. As I explain in my answer, it's a matter of whether you are talking _between different actors_. You can think of those as thread contexts (but don't).

Answer (score 0):

> SessionManager.shared.$isAuthenticated is not an async function, it's a simple published property. Why would you have to await a published property?

It's not what because of what SessionManager is, it's because of what the context is. `listenForAuthStatusChanges` is an `async` method. Therefore the compiler takes over and enforces thread-safety. The `await` makes sure that two possibly conflicting things do not take place at the same time. You cannot talk to one actor from another without saying `await`.

> What does @MainActor have to do with async/await

It has *everything* to do with async/await. It is *part* of async/await. Or rather, they are both part of structured concurrency.

> why does it's use negate the need for the await

Because it guarantees that your code and the session manager code run on the *same actor* — namely the main actor. Now you are *not* talking to one actor from another, so `await` is not needed.

Comment: Yet annoyingly, its parent context isn't guaranteed to be applied in a Combine sink, just like using `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` doesn't apply MainActor context to any code inside the sink. So if you change the Combine sink to `receive` on a different queue, the code inside the sink will still assume the context of the parent actor (e.g. `MainActor` in this example)

Comment: Well you shouldn't be combining (sorry) Combine and async/await. But that wasn't the question that was posed.

Comment: eh, it's perfectly fine to combine the two. async/await doesn't have a pub/sub pattern, and it's perfectly plausible to need to do a async operation (like a network call) in response to a subscription (like storing remotely how much of a podcast you listened to in response to a AVPlayer currentTime subscriber)